# IAM role based on an existing set of credentials from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've received a set of credentials (access key and secret) that were generated for me to access a different AWS account's resources, in this case specific S3 buckets.
Can I define an IAM role in my account, based on these keys?
I would like not to embed the credentials directly on the machines in my account that will access those resources.

Just to clarify, I know that access can be given directly from the other account to a role in my account. However given that I already have the set of keys, I would like to set up my own roles without needing to ask for an admin operation in the other account every time I make a change.

Thanks

Comment: No. You can get the credentials for a given role but you cannot create a role for a given set of credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

IAM roles are not "based on" other credentials.  They are primary entities, identities independent of any user or credential set.

Consider the documented description of a role, with a couple of highlights to illustrate the gaps:

> An IAM role is similar to a user, in that it **is an AWS identity** with permission policies that determine what the identity can and cannot do in AWS. However, instead of being uniquely associated with one person, a role is intended to be assumable by anyone who needs it. Also, **a role does not have any credentials (password or access keys) associated with it**. Instead, if a user is assigned to a role, access keys are created dynamically and provided to the user. *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I can't associate the role with the keys, but I guess that in order to keep it somewhat secure, I would use KMS and store the keys encrypted, and would give the IAM role the permissions to read those keys in runtime.